# Jetpack Compose Desktop – MaterialTheme.colors.background Not Working

Tags: kotlin, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

### Setting MaterialTheme.colors

I'm trying to make a very basic window in Jetpack Compose for **Desktop** (not mobile), but I'm having some difficulties with changing the colors of the window. I've looked at some tutorials and examples, but maybe I don't quite understand how color themes are correctly implemented.
The code that I wrote *should* create a window with a dark background, but the window when the program runs is white.
Please provide any insights you can as to what I am doing wrong.

##### Code (Kotlin)

```
import androidx.compose.desktop.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.*


fun main() = Window(
    title = "Window",
    resizable = false,
    size = IntSize(1200, 800),
) {
    MaterialTheme(colors = darkColors()) {

    }
}
```

##### Window

[image: light-themed window]

##### Other Info

**macOS** Big Sur
**IntelliJ** 2021.2
**Jetpack Compose** 0.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MaterialTheme` only provides colors for all views inside the container, it does not create or render the view.

Most Material components will use these colors as default values, but you can also use these colors in your views using, for example, `MaterialTheme.colors.background`.

You need to put some view inside, size it and apply some background color, for example:

```kotlin
MaterialTheme(colors = darkColors()) {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(MaterialTheme.colors.background))
}
```

Comment: The question remains, how to make the window in dark mode? I would expect it to theme the window background in a dark gray color.

Comment: @Chapz it doesn't seems to be supported so far, you can [create a feature request](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/new), or made a custom one based on [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Window_API_new#draggable-window-area) approach for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Scaffold** to see changes.
In your example:

```
...
MaterialTheme(colors = darkColors()) {
    Scaffold {
        // your content
    }
}
...
```

You can read about it:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material
or here:
https://metanit.com/kotlin/jetpack/4.11.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who came here and is using material 3. Material 3 uses `colorScheme` instead of `colors`.
Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#m2_1) page for the changes